# How many binary heaps can I create from n elements WITH duplicates?

Tags: algorithm, tree, heap, combinatorics, binary-heap

I know how to count the number of possible heaps with distinct elements such as {1, 2, 3, 4}.
But if I wanted to count the number of heaps looking like this:

> {1, 2, 3, **3**, 4}

How do I rewrite **f(N) = (N−1 C L) * f(L) * f(R)** to be able to work with duplicates?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Happy Coding. SO 
is about fixing Code - yours is a bit math-heavy and code-light. Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again to see what kind of topics SO handles. math.stackexchange.com would be a good thing to search for this kind of questions ( before posting it there as well ).

Comment: If there are 3 items, there are two possible heaps. But if one of those items is a duplicate, then there's really only one heap. You can probably generalize this: that if there are duplicates, the answer is `f(n) / (maxDuplicates)`.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Im sorry, Ill try to post only related stuff from now on.

Comment: @JimMischel Thank you for the reply. I was thinking about this, but it doesnt work for higher numbers in general. With for example 5 elements in heap, you can build 8 heaps. But when there are 2 duplicite numbers, you can build 6.
I have even written a program in Python to prove me right, but since I need the written formula with N elements, it does not help me much.

Comment: With the items 1-5, you have the following 8 valid heaps: `[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,5,4],[1,3,2,4,5],[1,3,2,5,4],[1,2,5,3,4],[1,2,5,4,3],[1,2,4,5,3],[1,2,4,3,5`. If you have the items `1,2,3,3,5`, you end up with 8 valid heaps, but only four of them are unique. The other four are duplicates.